# switch views using a button, going to a table view, iphone

Tags: iphone, uiview, button, tableview

My program has 4 buttons and each button calls a different table view. That works fine, but my problem is, the view controller I'm using brings up a table view that covers up my navigation bar and my tab bar. I need to replace that coding with something that will bring up a table and not cover up my nav and tab bars. Here is the coding I'm using:
-(IBAction)buttonNorthWest {

```
NorthWestViewController *nwController = [[NorthWestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NorthWestView" bundle:nil];
self.nwViewController = nwController;
[self.view insertSubview:nwViewController.view atIndex:0];


[self presentModalViewController:nwViewController animated:YES];


[nwController release];
```

}

The [self presentModalViewController....] is the problem. Does anyone know how I can replace that code with something that keeps my nav and tab bars?

Thanks,
Jaime

Comment: Do you have an update on any of this?

Answer (score 3):

On the iPhone, all modal view controllers *must* be full screen as seen here http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/modalPresentationStyle

As an alternative you could display the tableview as a subview and adjust the frame so that it does not overlap the nav or toolbar.

Comment: Sorry, I've been away, so haven't done anything with this code in quite some time. I am grateful for your response and will give the subview a try.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you have any other questions. I'd be more than glad to help.